# Can't Post a Form in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.10

It's my first real project in Django and I'm kinda noob here :))

In my index page I need some information from the user and then post it to another view.

here what I found:

```
NoReverseMatch at /download/
Reverse for 'progress' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P<download_id>[0-9]+)/progress/$']
```

---

View Page:

```
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    model = Download
    template_name = 'download/index.html'

def progress(request, download_link):
    download = models.Download(link=download_link, status = 0)
    download.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('download:detail', args=(download.id,)))
```

---

Index page:

```
<form class="download" action="{% url 'download:progress' download_link %}" method="post">
    <input type="input" name="download_link" id="download_link" class="input" placeholder="Enter the URL:" value="{{download_link}}" required/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Download">
</form>
```

---

Model:

```
class Download(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

---

URLs:

```
app_name = 'download'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<download_id>[0-9]+)/progress/$', views.progress, name='progress'),
]
```

---

I'm using latest stable Django at this time (v1.10)

Comment: Where does `download_link` variable in the template come from?

Comment: @ozgur It comes from the textbox

Comment: You look for `download_id` in the url but you are sending `download_link` instead.

Comment: @ozgur Actually I've tried to pass `download_id` and It didn't worked.
No luck again :(

Comment: Can you try `object.id`?

Comment: @ozgur I tried it and no luck there.

Comment: I think the problem is in your urls.py, please make an edit and let us see what you got there.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the source code is there anything after the `/download/` path? If `download_link` is not passed in `context` it means nothing to your form's `action` attribute. You are trying to get it's value in the form, but the `html` is generated on page load, before the user can enter it.

In order to do something with input you receive from a form, you need to pass it to a `view` function via `GET` or `POST` request. Only `GET` requests add arguments in the url and the form takes care of it - no need for you to specify it in `action`.

In your case you could do something like this:

**view:**

```
def progress(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        download_link = request.POST['download_link']
        download = models.Download(link=download_link, status = 0)
        download.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('download:detail', args=(download.id,)))
```

**template:**

```
<form class="download" action="{% url 'download:progress' %}" method="post">
    <input type="input" name="download_link" id="download_link" class="input" placeholder="Enter the URL:" required/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Download">
</form>
```

Also, in the `view` function you should probably think of a way to check if `Download` instance with these data exists and if creating a new instance pass information for the other fields too.

Change your `progress` url to `url(r'^progress$', views.progress, name='progress')` (without the trailing slash!). That way the url should be resolvable and the `view` function should be able to recieve `POST` data. From here you can continue modifying to get the result you want.

There is plenty of information on forms in Django's docs. You should go through it to gain better understanding of the subject - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/

Comment: It didn't work and I add the `urls.py` to the question.